¿Como obtener la fecha mas antigua registrada en una tabla con filtros en excel?

Buen día, debo hallar la fecha mas antigua y mas reciente en la que se registraron los ingresos según el nombre.
Logre hallar la fecha más reciente con:
=MAX(SI(Arrendamientos[Nombre]=E148;SUBTOTALES(103;DESREF($C$4;FILA(Arrendamientos[Nombre])-MIN(FILA(Arrendamientos[Nombre]));0))*Arrendamientos[Fecha]))
Pero no he logrado hacerlo con la fecha mas antigua, al realizar el filtro mi formula no funciona.
Lo intente con esta formula:
=AGREGAR(5;5;Arrendamientos[Fecha])
Me arroja la fecha mas antigua según el filtro, pero no se como individualizarla segun el nombre, es decir como hago para saber cual es la fecha mas antigua en la que ingresaron arrendamientos por construcciones y cual es la fecha mas antigua en la que ingresaron por equipos de oficina.
Muchas gracias

Puedes probar las siguientes fórmulas MIN(SI(C2:C141=E148; B2:B141)) para la fecha más antigua y MAX(SI(C2:C141=E148; B2:B141)) para la fecha más reciente y te darán las fechas más antigua y más reciente de un nombre específico de todos los que ha realizado.
Para las que están filtrados utiliza SI.ERROR(AGREGAR(14;6;$B$2:$B$141/(SUBTOTALES(3;DESREF($B$2;FILA($B$2:$B$141)-FILA($B$2);0))($C$2:$C$141=$E$148)); 1);"No se reportan ingresos entre las fechas") para la fecha más reciente y SI.ERROR(AGREGAR(15;6;$B$2:$B$141/(SUBTOTALES(3;DESREF($B$2;FILA($B$2:$B$141)-FILA($B$2);0))($C$2:$C$141=$E$148)); 1);"No se reportan ingresos entre las fechas") para las fecha más antigua.
Está fórmula te dará la cantidad de veces que aparece en el rango filtrado
SUMAPRODUCTO(SUBTOTALES(3;DESREF(C2;FILA(C2:C141)-FILA(C2);0))*(C2:C141=E148)).
en la celda E148 está el nombre que quieres buscar los ingresos

Gracias @José Lenzano, es exactamente lo que necesitaba. La función SI.ERROR resolvió efectivamente mi problema, solo cambie que la formula validara luego del encabezado y le agregue (*), quedando de la siguiente manera:  para la fecha más reciente SI.ERROR(AGREGAR(14;6;$B$4:$B$141/(SUBTOTALES(3;DESREF($B$4;FILA($B$4:$B$141)-FILA($B$4);0))*($C$4:$C$141=$E$148)); 1);"No se reportan ingresos entre las fechas") y para la mas antigua SI.ERROR(AGREGAR(15;6;$B$4:$B$141/(SUBTOTALES(3;DESREF($B$4;FILA($B$4:$B$141)-FILA($B$4);0))*($C$4:$C$141=$E$148)); 1);"No se reportan ingresos entre las fechas")

No estoy seguro de si entiendo la pregunta pero SUBTOTAL por defecto puede calcular el min/max sobre datos filtrados. Ejemplo sobre datos sin filtrar:

Las 4 fórmulas en el rango D14:D18 son:
=MIN(B5:B9)
=MAX(B5:B9)
=SUBTOTALES(5;B5:B9)
=SUBTOTALES(4;B5:B9)

Las mismas fórmulas pero filtrando datos (ocultamos la primera y última opción)

Fíjate que SUBTOTAL ha cambiado de valor y da los valores min/max según el filtro en activo

Gracias @Esei por responder, pero lo que estoy intentando hacer es obtener la fecha mínima en la que se alquilaron equipos de oficina por ejemplo. Algo como =MIN(SI((Arrendamientos[Nombre]="Equipos de oficina");Arrendamientos[Fecha])) pero omitiendo los valores ocultos. (solo filtro activo)

@JACDanubioAzul ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir unos datos de ejemplo (no hace falta que sean reales) que podamos copiar y pegar? También el resultado esperado. Puedes usar tablas markdown

la respuesta de @José Lenzano resolvió mi problema, muchas gracias por tu interes
